# Style and name of this kind of conditional: "Erfolgt die Zahlung nicht bald, so sind wir berechtigt …"

Tags: subjunctive, subordinate-clause, connotation

It's kind of basic, but I don't find the name of that construction. I've never learnt it, just pops up very often in newspapers and contracts.

The formula is something like:

```
Verb (oft in Konjunktiv) + Subjekt (+ vll. irrelevantes Ding) 
+ Komma (,) + so + Verb + Subjekt + usw.
```

For instance:

> Entstünden Schwierigkeiten bei der Installation, so sagen Sie uns Bescheid.

or, without subjunctive,

> Erfolgt die Zahlung nicht bald, sind wir berechtigt Ihren Vertrag zu kündigen.

If I understand correctly, that means

> Wenn Schwierigkeiten entstehen (würden), können sie uns Bescheid sagen.

and

> Wenn sie nicht zahlen, werden wir ihren Vertrag kündigen.

respectively. In case it's correct (for I'm not sure if the `so` and the subjunctive are  mandatory),

- what is the name (if any) and possible usage field of that construction?

I'm not confindent to use it, since I think it could sound menacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contracted form of conditional ("Bedingungssatz", "Konditionalsatz") using subclauses ("Nebensätze") with verb in first position ("V1-Stellung").

It's explained [here (German Wikipedia)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung#V1-Stellung_in_Nebens.C3.A4tzen).