# Sentence starts with a verb but not an 'if' construction

Tags: translation, subordinate-clause

Example snippet from [here](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/stil/drinnen-draussen/fg2000-wolfgang-feierbachs-wohnhaus-aus-plastik-von-1968-16688577-p2.html):

> Es war der Stoff, aus dem in den Sechzigern Träume gemacht waren:
> **Hatten** nur ein Jahrzehnt vor Feierbach die Amerikaner noch
> Flugzeugteile daraus hergestellt, stürzten sich nun vor allem Künstler
> und Architekten auf das zugleich äußert robuste wie hochwertige
> Material.

I've always thought when a sentence starts with a verb and it's not a question, command or "let's" type structure, then it must be an "if" sentence.

It seems in this snippet, that is not the case. It's not "if the Americans made aircrafts parts from it only a decade before Ferierbach", but "the Americans made aircrafts parts from it only a decade before Ferierbach".

Is this standard grammar, or is the author being creative or poetic?

Comment: Similar: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26036/35111 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11173/35111 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35456/35111

Comment: Note it is not an *if*, which is omitted here, but something like *As opposed to [a decade before, where...]*.

Comment: I made the mistake of not reading the example, but merely the accompanying text. I agree with @guidot that the meaning is not conditional. It could be adversative, concessive or [*irrelevanzkonditional*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrelevanzkonditional).

Answer (score 2):

This sentence doesn't just start with a verb, it starts with a subordinate clause. The entire subordinate clause is in "postion 1", if you will. The "second position" is occupied by the verb "stürzen".

If you reconstruct this, you could write: "Es stürzten sich nun vor allem [...], nachdem nur ein Jahrzehnt vor Feierbach die Amerikaner noch Flugzeugteile daraus hergestellt hatten."

As you can see, the verb "haben" now is put at the end of the subordinate clause. To learn more about this, you can research the [V1-Stellung in Nebensätzen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung#V1-Stellung_in_Nebens%C3%A4tzen):

> Verb-Erst-Sätze erscheinen als Nebensätze mit der Bedeutung spezieller Satztypen (kausal, konditional, konzessiv o. ä.), wobei diese Interpretationen manchmal durch entsprechende Modalpartikeln gestützt werden müssen. [...] In diesen Sätzen erscheint das Verb anstelle einer nebensatzeinleitenden Konjunktion am Satzanfang:
>
> > Bedingungssätze (Konditionale): (Alternative: Konjunktion wenn …)
> > **Hätte ich mehr Zeit gehabt**, hätte ich einen längeren Brief geschrieben.
>
> > Konzessivssätze: (Alternative: wenn … auch)
> > **War der Auftritt auch** etwas misslungen, so hatte er immerhin Aufmerksamkeit erregt.

As for your next question:

> Is this standard grammar, or is the author being creative or poetic?

Yes, it is standard grammar, and yes, the author does it to make their writing less boring.

Comment: But looking at a sentence of this nature, how can I tell if it's an "if" sentence or it's starting with a subordinate clause?

Comment: @HPB: Context. I can't think of any other way.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a summary of what‘s behind the link „V1-Stellung in Nebensätzen“.

Comment: @HPB, an if-sentence would have Konjunktiv.